# What is the right way to create integer(low precision) linear layer in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

Let's say that I want to create a simple single layer network.
The typical way I would do it would be:

```
class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_feat, out_feat):
        super(FuncModel, self).__init__()

        self.layer1 = Linear(in_feat, out_feat, bias=True, dtype=torch.float32)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)

torch_model = MyModel(in_feat, out_feat)
```

This creates a layer with random weights.

My question is, **how do I create a similar model for an int8 model?**

I don't want to quantize a float32 based model. I want to build a model with int8 weights which will take int8 inputs. Doing the following throws the requires_grad error as shown below:

```
class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_feat, out_feat):
        super(FuncModel, self).__init__()

        self.layer1 = Linear(in_feat, out_feat, bias=True, dtype=torch.int8)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)

torch_model = MyModel(in_feat, out_feat)
```

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.weight = Parameter(torch.empty((out_features, in_features), **factory_kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/parameter.py", line 37, in __new__
    return torch.Tensor._make_subclass(cls, data, requires_grad)
RuntimeError: Only Tensors of floating point and complex dtype can require gradients
```

I also tried it with `with torch.no_grad():` to no avail.

Let's ignore training for now. I just want a model with random integer weights so I can perform inference. How can I achieve that?

Comment: There's information in the pytorch documentation about quantizing a model. Does this help?  https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html

Comment: I did read that documentation page. It is not clear how to achieve this without quantization overhead during run time. The inputs are assumed to be in float irresepective of the quantizatio method and thus have an overhead during run time.